# link opens PDF on iPhone but not on laptop

Tags: html, ios, pdf, codepen

I'm working on a simple project at [Codepen](https://codepen.io/gonzalo2000/pen/LBpXby), mostly links and Bootstrap modals. My link `<a href="https://www.lcps.org/cms/lib/VA01000195/Centricity/Domain/4/2018-19%20teacher%20calendar.pdf" target="_blank">Teacher Calendar</a>` opens the PDF on both Safari and Chrome on the iPhone, but not on my Macbook (OSX El Capitan v. 10.11.6). I can, however, open the same website on the laptop directly from a Google search. Is there a fix to the html that can solve this?

Comment: Sounds like you need to install a PDF viewer on the desktop.

Comment: I can view the page if I open it from the Google results page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a file name problem, change the filename of your pdf removing the white spaces.
if this doesn't solve your problem, try to compress the pdf.

Good luck.

**UPDATE:** I believe the PDF is protected for hot-links you might never make it work. you better upload it in your own hosting.